# RMS value of any periodic voltage or current

Tags: rms

How using calculus can be derived the RMS value of any periodic voltage or current?

Comment: Try googling 'calculate RMS' you may be surprised how many folk have already answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the formula for the periodic waveform then you square the formula then take the average over the waveform's period.

Taking the average firstly requires integrating the formula and plugging in the limits of time for the start of the period and the end of the period. Secondly, you divide through by the period converting area of the waveform to a mean amplitude.

Then take the square root.

**EDIT**  An alterative way of looking at RMS - imagine the periodic waveform were applied to a resistor and ask yourself what the power would be - it would be \$ V^2/R \$
. To get the "effective" power you need to average the power waveform (integration then dividing by time period).

The mean/average power you have now calculated could have been created by a DC voltage and to find this dc voltage, equate the average power to \$ V(dc)^2/R \$
. This conveniently gets rid of the resistor, R and by taking the square root you return an equivalent DC voltage that would achieve the same power into any abitrary resistor. This is RMS; an equivalent DC voltage that would create the same power as the waveform.

Squaring is not done to make the waveform always positive (rather like the ABS function) so that the average isn't zero. Squaring is absolutely fundamental to the process of converting to a power and then finding the equivalent DC voltage that would generate that same power. If you did ABS(sinewave) then averaged it, then took the square root you would not get true RMS.

Comment: Is there a reason why for performing rms the function needed to be squared?

Comment: @user7777777 Not squaring the signal is not an option. The idea behind RMS is that you try and calculate the power of the signal into 1 ohm and this of course needs a V^2/R or I^R - as R=1 this means V squared or I squared. So you get power into 1 ohm then you average the power (integration). Then you take the square root and this relieves the formula of its dependence on 1 ohm. Remember, the RMS value of a waveform is the equivalent DC voltage that would heat up a resistor by the same value.

Comment: Squaring has nothing to do with \$\dfrac{V^2}{R}\$ or \$I^2R\$. Consider the function \$v(t)=170sin188t\$, basic US line power. Take the average value of a sine wave and the answer is zero because it oscillates around zero. Squaring is essentially acting as an absolute value function that allows the function in question to remain both integral and differentiable.

Comment: @MattYoung No, I disagree. Squaring is not acting as ABS - ABS would convert a sinewave to a full wave rectified signal. You would still need to square this FW rectified signal to achieve RMS. Squaring is the key - not ABS.

Comment: @MattYoung - consider a signal that is always positive - are you saying that you wouldn't need to square the signal and in-effect you'd just average the waveform and then take the square root?

Comment: @Andyaka This is going to be entirely too long for a comment. Let me make all of this into an answer.

Comment: @user7777777, "RMS" stands for "root mean square", meaning square root of the mean of the square. You take the square of the signal (before taking the mean and then the square root) because you can't get the square root of the mean of the squared value of the signal without starting off by calculating the squared value of the signal.